# How bad is it to re-evaluate an unchanging condition within a loop?

Tags: c, loops, optimization, conditional-statements

I am writing a .y4m video generator in C that takes all the .bmp images in a directory and writes them to a .y4m video file (after appropriately converting the colours to YCbCr format).

One of the command-line options I am allowing to be specified is whether the .bmp files should be deleted during the video generation. Right now, this happens right at the end of the program, but it would be best for it to occur as images are written (to not increase disk space usage by more than 1 frame at at a time, since the .y4m files are uncompressed video, so can get pretty big).

Thus, if the delete option is specified, the deleting should take place within one of the 5 main loops I have (there is one for each colour-subsampling scheme). The loops have lots of code within, however, so I really would like to avoid duplicating them.

In summary, even though this:

```
if (delete) {
    while (bmps_remain) {
        // do lots of funky stuff
        remove(path_to_single_bmp);
    }
}
else {
    while (bmps_remain) {
        // do the exact same funky stuff as above
        // ... but do not delete bmp file
    }
}
```

... is better than this:

```
while (bmps_remain) {
    // lots and lots of code
    if (delete)
        remove(path_to_single_bmp);
}
```

... how much of a difference does it really make, and how frowned upon is it to opt for the second option (taking performance into account as much as possible), given that the second option re-evaluates the (unchanging) condition during each iteration of the loop?

Even though it would probably get compiled into some kind of `cmp` instruction (probably followed by a kind of `jnz`) which would only take a fraction of a second to perform, this situation occurs commonly in programming, so I would be interested to hear people's opinions.

Thanks.

P.S. The first option would produce a lot of code duplication in my case (and I would prefer to not stick everything into functions, given the previous layout of the program).

Comment: As long as it's just checking a scalar value, and you aren't doing thousands of them per second, I'd go with the more logical and readable code.

Comment: If the compiler can tell that the code never modifies `delete` in the loop, it may compile the second code as if it's the first. Modern compilers are very smart.

Comment: The amount of time it takes to do a test and conditional branch is trivial compared to the time it takes to remove a file or to write a new frame of video. If this were a leaf routine, modern desktop/notebook processors will cache information about the branch direction, and it will be correctly predicted in almost all iterations of the loop. It is probably not a leaf routine, since the loop is apparently doing work converting color formats, so the test and branch is trivial compared to that work.

Comment: @Barmar indeed, thank you, that's what I'm hoping for! Compilers truly are amazing

Comment: @EricPostpischil cheers for your comment, and yes, as you have pointed out, the I/O and numerical calculations that take place within the loop are extremely computationally expensive (as every single pixel has to be dealt with, and there are usually >1000000), so an extra machine instruction will literally add on <0.0001% to the total computation time

Comment: @Gregor: And thus, for this particular specific problem, it wasn't worth using even a couple of neuron-seconds to consider the question, much less involve the eyes and brains of a dozen viewers. As a general question, "How bad is it to do unnecessary computations in a loop?" is, like "How long is a piece of string?", unanswerable. It depends on how expensive the computation is and how expensive the loop is, so the answer could be anywhere between "irrelevant except to obsessive perfectionists" and "absolutely crucial if you want your computation to finish before the spacecraft crashes".

Comment: @rici And even in that latter case, it will only help if you've actually profiled your code and demonstrated the change actually improves performance.  Given optimizing compilers and deeply-pipelined CPU that have multiple instructions "executing" simultaneously, I've found that eyeball inspection of code to optimize it often has no impact.  **Profile** the code to identify the actual bottlenecks - what looks like a bottleneck quite often isn't in reality.  It's often something like that innocent-looking pointer/array dereference that causes a TLB miss or false sharing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `remove( path_to_single_bmp );` instruction is ***several orders of magnitude*** slower than your `if( invariant )`; therefore, it makes absolutely no sense to be worrying the slightest bit about the overhead of re-executing it in the loop.

More generally, an `if( invariant )` is so trivial as to never be worth considering for optimization, even if it only controls trivial code.

Even more generally, things like `if( invariant )` will be optimized by the C compiler in any way it sees fit, regardless of what your intentions are, so they are generally not worth considering.

And even more-more generally, one of the most important qualities of code is readability, (second only to correctness,) and more code is less readable than less code, so any approach that results in less code is preferable. In other words, any approach that requires more code is generally far worse than any approach that requires less code. Exceptions to this rule tend to be ***algorithmic*** optimizations, where you introduce an entire algorithm to achieve performance. (E.g. a hash map instead of a naive array scan.)  Tweaking and hacking code all over the place to squeeze clock cycles here and there never results in anything good.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. I was aware it was insignificant, but perhaps not up to the point that I really should not be paying much attention to it (especially when plonked inside loops that do stuff that are actually very slow). I will keep what you have said in mind for the future, cheers!